# Android: how to use OnCreate() when pressing backbutton

Tags: android, back-button, oncreate

When pressing the backbutton I want that, whatever screen will be loading, the onCreate() method will be executed. I want this because the screens must be refreshing when navigating through the app.

Do I need to override the back button method?

```
if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
{

    }
```

Comment: Calling the OnCreate() when the back button is pressed sounds like really bad practice. Anyway you can still override the OnBackPressed method

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you press the back button, the `onResume()` method is called, so instead of using `onCreate()`, use this and do whatever you need to do for refreshing the activity.

Comment: That's the right answer. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#Lifecycle

Comment: To get to know the Activity lifecycle a bit better I also suggest that you display a toast everytime the different methods of an Activity are triggered.. so in onResume() you Toast.makeText(this, "onResume()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); .. same in onStop() and onCreate(), onStart() etc :)

Answer (score 2):

You approach is wrong. onCreate() will only be called when the Activity is created. But everytime the Activity comes to the front the Method `onResume` will be called, this Method will also be called on the first start.
Look at the Activity Lifecycle for further info: http://fs01.androidpit.info/wiki/de/b/Beginners_Workshop_Activity_LC.png

Answer (score 1):

When an activity is coming from background its onResume() method will be called. You should update your UI there.

Answer (score 0):

f you want execute anything after the back button you have to override it. Can you just refresh some part of the activity, not the whole one?